# QR Code in Windows Store App

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, qr-code

I need to program a QR code reader in my Windows RT app, so I can get the ID of the specific item I am scanning.

I have found the source to a free QR code generator, but I cannot find the code to read the ID from the QR Code, so can anybody in here tell me, where I can find the source to a QR Reader or any other ways to read the QR Code e.g. Install a third-party program, which only reads the QR Code and sends the result back to my program

Comment: Please be careful with RT-related tagging.  [See meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152477/135887).

Comment: Modern UI apps, can't share info that way (only with the Share charm), which will make your QR code app moot, what you need is a WinRT library (or port yourself an existing one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at [ZXing.NET](http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/). It's an Open Source barcode scanner library, which includes support for QR codes. There is a WinRT port available on CodePlex. You will simply need to pass an image into the library to read the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, I had to manually write camera capture capability and then pass it on to ZXing. Check it out here - http://quirkd.wordpress.com/2015/02/18/reading-qr-codes-in-winrt-tricky/